# Recovering grub using Ubuntu Live USB

Tags: 14.04, boot, grub2, kernel, live-usb

I have Ubuntu 14.04 (64-bit) installed on a Dell server. I wanted to use one of the earlier kernel versions and I edited /etc/default/grub for this. It seems like I made something wrong. After updating grub, the system directly go to memory check. I am also not getting the grub menu for selecting a different kernel. How can I recover my system using live USB? I followed the steps given [here](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd). Unfortunately it did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to go will probably be to use boot-repair, download it from:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/files/

Burn the iso on a cd or create a live usb with unetbootin, available on:

http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/

Boot your system from cd or usb and startup boot-repair. Use recommended repairs.

Answer (score 0):

now you can fix it by another way, yeah no cli mode but gui. visit this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair i hope it can help you full